# Does Scala call method associated with declared type, or method associated with parent class

Tags: scala, oop

Say I have a class `Rectangle` with a method `shapeType` that prints `"rectangle"`, and a subclass `Square` that overrides this method to print `"square"`.

Say I then have a variable of declared type `Rectangle`, e.g. `var shape: Rectangle = ___`

I then reassign this variable to be a `Square`, e.g. `shape = new Square` (which is allowed as `Square < Rectangle`)

When I call `shape.shapeType`, will the compiler choose to print `"rectangle"`, or "`square`"?

Comment: Why don't you try it to see what happens? PS: What happens is not because of the compiler but the runtime.

Comment: I've tried it and gotten `"square"`, but its nearly 3am and I'm so doubtful of my coding ability at this point that I worry my code might be wrong.

Comment: Why would it be wrong? You have a square.

Comment: This is true, but couldn't I also say "The variable has type `Rectangle`, so why wouldn't we get `Rectangle`'s method?"

Comment: If the answer is `"square"` though that does make sense and answer my question so thank you

Comment: You are confusing types, with clases. And compile time with runtime. https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html

Comment: That link is very helpful, thank you